# Why doesn't PyCharm hint work with decorators?

Tags: python-3.x, generics, pycharm, type-hinting, typing

PyCharm Version: 2019.1.2

Python Version: 3.7

I am trying to use least code to reproduce the problem. And this is the snippet of my code:

```
def sql_reader():
    def outer(func):
        def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            return [{"a": 1, "b": 2}]

        return wrapped_function

    return outer


@sql_reader()
def function_read():
    return "1"


result = function_read()

for x in result:
    print(x['a'])
print(result)
```

Basically, what I am doing is to "decorate" some function to output different types. For example, in this snippet, the function being decorated is returning 1 which is *int*. However, in decorator, I change the behavior and return *list of dict*.

Functionally speaking, it works fine. But it looks like my IDE always complains about it which is annoying as below:
[image]

Is there anyway I can get rid of this warning message?

Answer (score 0):

With all due respect, you are using an over 3 year old version of PyCharm. I struggle to see a reason for this. The community edition is free and requires no root privileges to unpack and run on Linux systems. You should seriously consider upgrading to the latest version.

Same goes for Python by the way. You can install any version (including the latest) via [Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) without root privileges. Although the Python version requirement may be subject to external restrictions for the code you are working on, so that is just a suggestion. But for the IDE I see no reason to use such an outdated version.

---

Since I am not using your PyCharm version, I can not reproduce your problem. Version 2022.2.3 has no such issues with your code. Be that as it may, there are a few things you can do to make life easier for static type checkers (and by extension for yourself).

The first thing I would *always* suggest is to use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.wraps), when you are wrapping functions via a decorator. This preserves a lot of useful metadata about the wrapped function and even stores a reference to it in the wrapper's `__wrapped__` attribute.

The second is proper type annotations. This should go for *any* code you write, unless it really is just a quick-and-dirty draft script that you will only use once and then throw away. The benefits of proper annotations *especially* in conjunction with modern IDEs are huge. There are many resources out there explaining them, so I won't go into details here.

In this concrete case, proper type hints will remove ambiguity about the return types of your functions and should work with any IDE (bugs non withstanding). In my version of PyCharm the return type of your wrapper function is inferred to be `Any` because no annotations are present, which prevents any warning like yours to pop up, but also doesn't allow any useful auto-suggestions to be provided.

Here is what I would do with your code: (should be compatible with Python `3.7`)

```py
from functools import wraps
from typing import Any, Callable, Dict, List


AnyFuncT = Callable[..., Any]
ResultsT = List[Dict[str, int]]


def sql_reader() -> Callable[[AnyFuncT], Callable[..., ResultsT]]:
    def outer(func: AnyFuncT) -> Callable[..., ResultsT]:
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> ResultsT:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            return [{"a": 1, "b": 2}]
        return wrapper
    return outer


@sql_reader()
def function_read() -> str:
    return "1"
```

Adding `reveal_type(function_read())` underneath and calling `mypy` on this file results  in the following:

```
note: Revealed type is "builtins.list[builtins.dict[builtins.str, builtins.int]]"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

As you can see, at least `mypy` now correctly infers the type returned by the wrapper function we put around `function_read`. Your IDE *should* also correctly infer the types involved, but as I said I cannot verify this with my version.

Moreover, now PyCharm will give you auto-suggestions for methods available on the types involved:

```py
results = function_read()
first = results[0]
value = first["a"]
```

If I now start typing `results.`, PyCharm will suggest things like `append`, `extend` etc. because it recognizes `result` as a list. If I type `first.`, it will suggest `keys`, `values` etc. (inferring it as a dictionary) and if I type `value.` it will give options like `imag`, `real` and `to_bytes`, which are available for integers.

More information: [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/typing.html) module docs